# Android MediaPlayer, support for progressive download audio or not?

Tags: android, download, media-player, mp4, progressive

I'm currently performing a feasibility study where one of the questions is concerning the possibility to switch from streaming to progressive download of audio. By progressive download I mean that the audio files, which are hosted by a standard web server with nothing fancy on it, can be downloaded through standard http calls, and played back *before* the whole file is downloaded completely.

My company's has contracted external Android app developers, which now claim that although progressive download in the manner specified above works fine for the MP3 files but that it is not possible with the AAC MP4 files. I have no reason to doubt the developers, but I would love a second opinion. I've been researching this topic (by frantic googling) and find no reason for it not to work. I've also tested some existing players on the Android Market (MX player for instance) and they can play the files while downloading.

So my question is basically if anyone know **for a fact** that using the MediaPlayer component in Android (let's say versions 2.1 through 4.1), progressive download and playback before the AAC MP4 file is downloaded completely actually works?

Also, since the AAC codec and the MP4 container are vastly more complex than MP3, do we have to do something with our files when encoding them to ensure progressive download with the MediaPlayer component? When researching I found some information about some "faststart" option, and also "hinting" which may or may not be important (hinting seems to be one of the most "magical" topics... half of the articles/blogs say you need to hint, but the other half says that you definitely don't need to hint). Since I can play back progressively with MX Player, I am guessing that our encoding already performs whatever is needed, or am I wrong in this assumption?

Cheers!

Comment: I'd be curious to know what you eventually settled on.  Did your devs figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(disclaimer : that was done with video files, not music ones)

I have done that, it is completely feasible.

The trick with MP4 is to place the index at the /beginning/ of the file, rather than at the end where it usually is.

Comment: Interesting! You gave me some new words to use when researching. I found this: http://lists.apple.com/archives/quicktime-users/2010/Jul/msg00002.html which says "In order to be "fast start", the 'moov' atom (the movie header) needs to be at the beginning of the file so that it is downloaded first" and "If you see 'moov' in those first few bytes (bytes 5-8, to be exact), you're good". I opeed one of our audio files with HxD hex editor and I can see "¨™moov...lmvhd.." in the fifth byte. Does this mean that the index is indeed at the beginning of the file? Is index and "faststart" the same thing?

Comment: i have no idea, but the moov atom was indeed what i had to place at the beginning of the file to be able to play an incomplete file.

Comment: Thanks. One more question before I accept your answer: What Android versions did your app support?

Comment: Froyo and up, if my memory is correct. BTW, you'll find all actually supported formats here http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html